# Meteor js : lack of feedback on console

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have the following code:

```
if (Meteor.isClient)
    },
    'click .js-rate-image': 
        function (event){console.log("You have just cliked a star.");}
    });
    }`
```

Expecting console to output feedback as appearing inside the function.         However, there is no feedback on Firefox web console. I am trying to       figure out as to what is the problem but not winning.

Comment: You seems to have some unmatched brackets and parenthesis. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have created a Meteor event handler but you haven't attached it to any template. Also, that function will only run when you click a HTML element with the class `.js-rate-image`. It won't just log the statement when the app runs.

You need to create a template and attach this event handler to an element in the template.

I recommend you follow the [meteor tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app) to learn how this works.

Comment: Checked brackets and parentheses against Lecture's. Nothing seems different. Tried removing some brakets still got error. Already have correct html with templates i.e <p>{{>starsRating mutable=true class= "js-rate_image"}}</p>. 

Images get displayed and deleted very well. The problem occurs when testing event on console if clicking stars rating shading them in yellow. No proof on console!  Only errors i.e app.js:82 0
http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Stucked now and cannot finished a tutorial.